# Adding data to state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I imported the collections variable from another file and am now trying to add it to my state. How does that work?

---

Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {id, name, masterAssetId, tags}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
in p (at App.js:17)

---

Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {id, name, masterAssetId, tags}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
in p (at App.js:17)
in div (at App.js:16)

---

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import {collections} from "./data.js"

class App extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super()

        this.state = {
           collectionsarr: collections
        }
    }
  
  render(){
  return (
          <div className="App">
            <p>{this.state.collectionsarr[0]}</p>

            <h1>Charles</h1>

            {/* <h1>{collections[0].name}</h1> */}
          </div>
        )
  }
}

export default App
```

---

**data.js**

```
const collections = [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: "The Simpsons",
        masterAssetId: 13,
        tags: {
            name: "Cartoon",
            subTag: {
                name: "Simpsons family",
                subTag: {
                    name: "2014",
                },
            },
        },
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: "Super heroes",
        masterAssetId: 24,
        tags: {
            name: "DC Super heroes",
            subTag: {
                name: "2014",
            },
        },
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        name: "Toy story",
        masterAssetId: 31,
        tags: {
            name: "Disney",
            subTag: {
                name: "Pixar",
                subTag: {
                    name: "Original movie",
                    subTag: {
                        name: "2010",
                    },
                },
            },
        },
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        name: "Ninjago",
        masterAssetId: 42,
        tags: {
            name: "Ninja",
            subTag: {
                name: "Secret Ninja Force",
                subTag: {
                    name: "2017",
                },
            },
        },
    },
];

const assets = [
    {
        id: 11,
        name: "Homer Simpson",
        path: "Homer.jpg",
        collectionId: 1,
    },
    {
        id: 12,
        name: "Lisa Simpson",
        path: "Lisa.jpg",
        collectionId: 1,
    },
    {
        id: 13,
        name: "Bart Simpson",
        path: "Bart.jpg",
        collectionId: 1,
    },
    {
        id: 14,
        name: "Marge Simpson",
        path: "Marge.jpg",
        collectionId: 1,
    },
    {
        id: 15,
        name: "Grampa Simpson",
        path: "Grampa.jpg",
        collectionId: 1,
    },
    {
        id: 16,
        name: "Maggie Simpson",
        path: "Maggie.jpg",
        collectionId: 1,
    },
    {
        id: 21,
        name: "Green Lantern",
        path: "Green lantern.jpg",
        collectionId: 2,
    },
    {
        id: 22,
        name: "Flash",
        path: "Flash.jpg",
        collectionId: 2,
    },
    {
        id: 23,
        name: "Batman",
        path: "Batman.jpg",
        collectionId: 2,
    },
    {
        id: 24,
        name: "Superman",
        path: "Superman.jpg",
        collectionId: 2,
    },
    {
        id: 31,
        name: "Buzz Lightyear",
        path: "Buzz.jpg",
        collectionId: 3,
    },
    {
        id: 32,
        name: "Alien",
        path: "Alien.jpg",
        collectionId: 3,
    },
    {
        id: 41,
        name: "Spinjitzu training Nya",
        path: "Nya.jpg",
        collectionId: 4,
    },
    {
        id: 42,
        name: "Master Wu",
        path: "Wu.jpg",
        collectionId: 4,
    },
    {
        id: 43,
        name: "Lloyd",
        path: "Lloyd.jpg",
        collectionId: 4,
    },
];

export const getCollectionsAsync = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(() => resolve(collections), 1000));
};

export const getAssetByIdAsync = (assetId) => {
    const asset = assets.find((a) => a.id === assetId);

    if (!asset) {
        throw new Error("Asset not found" + assetId);
    }

    return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(() => resolve(asset), 500));
};

export const getAssetsByCollectionAsync = (collectionId) => {
    const collectionAssets = assets.filter((asset) => asset.collectionId === collectionId);

    return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(() => resolve(collectionAssets), 1000));
};

export {collections}
```

Comment: This code looks fine to me. What issues are you experiencing with it?

Comment: @richytong: I added the errors

Comment: can you share data.js?

Comment: added data.js in the question

Comment: what do you want to print inside <p> tag?

Comment: all names inside collections

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `map` through the `collectionsarr` and write every object's name of collectionsarr

```js
 return (
    <div className="App">
      {this.state.collectionsarr.map((collection) => (
        <p>{collection.name}</p>
      ))}
     <h1>Charles</h1>
    </div>
   )
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with this line

```
<p>{this.state.collectionsarr[0]}</p>
```

where you are trying to render an object. If you want to render a JSON view of your data in the `p` tag, you can change it to this:

```
<p>{JSON.stringify(this.state.collectionsarr[0])}</p>
```